# What does the term "economy is flat" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

While watching [this](https://www.ted.com/talks/ray_dalio_how_to_build_a_company_where_the_best_ideas_win/transcript) video the speaker says:

> [5:03]: The economy is now flat

What does "flat" exactly mean in this context?

Comment: It means that charts showing economic indicators such as GDP, average earnings, etc. are [flatlining](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flatline) *(at a low level and not increasing).*

Comment: Draw a graph of some economic measure, such as GDP.  Is the graph  line rising, falling, or flat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meaning of "flat" [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flat):

> If profits, sales, etc. are flat, they are not growing or increasing:

So when the speaker says "the economy is now flat", he is stating that there hasn't been any remarkable shift (increase or decrease) in the economy.